# Reading a csv using browserify - fs.readFileSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, csv, browserify

I'm trying to read a csv file into the browser:

```
// index.js

const parse = require('csv-parse/lib/sync')
const filePath='./data.csv';

var fs = require('fs');
var file = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8');
```

running `browserify -t brfs index.js > bundle.js` results in the error:

`Uncaught TypeError: fs.readFileSync is not a function` in the browser console.

Any help or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: fs is only available in the backend, it's part of the node.js API

Comment: but isn't the point of brfs to allow for fs to be used?
https://github.com/browserify/brfs